# Is it good practice to add a condition in a state definition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Relatively new to react. I've not seen this done often. Example:

```
this.state = {
  varName: x.length != 0 ? 'Something' : null
}
```

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong with that. This is not about React itself, but general design practise

Comment: what is `x` ? Is it a props?

Comment: yes in this case x is a props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why that wouldn't work, but you'd have to be careful about where `x` is being defined. Usually I just leave all my state variables set to null or default values and then update them in `componentWillMount`, when I'll grab the information needed from props, localstorage, etc

Comment: Thank you. Moving it to componentWillMount since that will not force a re-render.

Comment: @Christa awesome! If this worked for you would you accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you will define the initial state in the constructor with initial values, then on a component lifecycle, you could setState to that condition. Example

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            varName:null
        };
 }

componentDidMount() {
       // perhaps here evaluate your x value and then set the state
        var x = something such as fetch or props passed
        this.setState({
          varName: x.length != 0 ? 'Something' : null
        })
}
```